# How to draw lines for diagrams?

Tags: qgis, diagram

Just before submitting bug: in Diagrams, there is possibility to use Position AroundPoint or OverPoint. Whatever I choose Line Options selection stays gray: I can't choose any line.

So, I suggest that this Line Option -option will draw line between actual point and re-located diagram. However, it doesn't work in my QuantumGIS 1.8.0 (win or Ubuntu). I haven't test it on 1.9

[image]

Rgs,

Pekka

Comment: I suggest you try a recent dev build as it might be fixed there.

Comment: Hmm, I need to figure where to install this dev-version. I don't want mess my "production" enviroment...

Comment: You can install qgis-master on Windows using the osgeo4w installer. This won't mess any other qgis installation you may have. On OsX also is possible to install 1.8 and master while on Linux it is trickier.

Comment: Checked on 1.9.0 -master (code revision 5a0d2f5): no difference. Maybe be I submit a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to draw a line between a object and its associated diagram.

The "Line Options" can only be used for line features (thus greyed out here) and define the position of a diagram relative to the line. In the current development versions and starting from 2.0 stable release, this option will be hidden instead of disabled.

Comment: Yes, I submit a bug. But later on developers clarify situation: this is just for line feature, but not for other diagrams.