# How to print pie charts in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, printing

I added pie charts via text-file to my map.

When printing the map they get lost. Does anyone know how to print them?
QGIS also seems to delet some charts, when there are to many at one place. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: you can try to overlay the pie charts after in GIMP for example.

Comment: Thanks radek, I allready tried that. It works but its hard to differentiate one chart from another

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and I didn't found perfect solution.

However, I made pie charts in Quantum GIS, then I export pie charts to SVG-file. Then I finalize my map with Inkscape: manually drag pie's to better place. Result:

[image: Example of pie charts in Inscape]

I have also other solution in my mind. I'd like to add these pie chart "movements" to my Spatialite table. Then I can have view in Spatialite to draw pie charts in best places.

I also suggest that automatic re-placement of pie's should be in QGIS. But this request has been postpone to future releases (after 2.x).

P

Comment: See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32591/how-to-draw-lines-for-diagrams

Comment: Thanks a lot posiki! Its working perfectly, that really solves my problem